# CFBundleVersion: still getting error with validation

Tags: ios, xcode, build, app-store-connect

I know there are a lot of questions about that but I still found issues understanding how the version numbers work.

This is my app changelog on the Apple Store:

- Version 1.2

  - Build 1.2.0
- Version 1.1

  - Build 1.1.1
  - Build 1.1.0

Now I'm going to upload a new update version providing bug fixes (let's call it, for instance 1.2.1). Please tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

---

**Step 1** - Set the values in Xcode

[image: Versions]

---

**Step 2** - Add a new version in iTunes Connect named 1.2.1

[image]

---

**Step 3** - Upload via Xcode the new build

---

**Step 4** - Got this error

[image]

I really cannot figure it out what I'm missing. Did I confuse CFBundleShortVersionString with CFBundleVersion?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but i think that the Build-Number must be an Integer

Comment: @FelixSFD Incorrect. I use a standard 3 point version number x.y.z for both version and build number. Works just fine.

Comment: @rmaddy That might work, but it's wrong.  A version number and build number are different things.  However that's nothing to do with the question, which I think the error message explains pretty well.

Comment: @trojanfoe I want to add the build 1.2.1 below the 1.2 version (looking at the schema I wrote at the beginning of my question). This is just a little change, I don't want to sign this version as 1.3. Maybe I'm little confused

Comment: @trojanfoe I understand it's not directly related to the question but Felix's comment is incorrect. And using an "x.y.z" version number for the build is not wrong. The documentation for `CFBundleVersion` states it must be a period separated list of at most 3 non-negative numbers. So it can be "x", "x.y", or "x.y.z".

Comment: @rmaddy And yet Apple break that rule themselves with numbers like `12345AB`.

Comment: Only change version to 1.2.1 and build in 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have an approved app with a version of 1.2.

Your update must have a higher version number (as well as a higher build version).

Your new update must be version 1.2.1 or 1.3 (or really anything higher than 1.2). This is what the error is telling you.

To be clear, it is the "Version" field on the Info tab in Xcode that must be updated to something beyond "1.2". In the Info.plist, this corresponds to the `CFShortBundleVersion` key.

Comment: I think you should clarify that the change needs to be made to `CFBundleShortVersionString` as that's the value that iTunes in validating and complaining about.

Comment: +1 This is correct, the version is actually a string, which however can still be evaluated against another version string. e.g 1.2.1 > 1.2 and also 1.2a > 1.2

Comment: "**approved** app" Maybe this is what I was missing. I uploaded app with same version number but different builds successfully in the past. How do I achieve that? Maybe 'cause those version wasn't approved?

Comment: @user3582537 Correct. Once a version is approved, the next update must have a higher version number. It is the version (not build) that the user sees.